# Prove that $f=(x+i)^{10}+(x-i)^{10}$ have all real roots

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

We have $f=(x+i)^{10}+(x-i)^{10}$ and we need to prove that $f$ have all the roots in $\mathbb{R}$.

Here is all my steps:

- Suppose that $z\in\mathbb{R}$ is a root of $f\Rightarrow (z+i)^{10}+(z-i)^{10}=0$

Therefore: $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{10}\left[\left(\dbinom{10}{k}\cdot z^{10-k}\cdot i^k\right)\left(1+(-1)^k\right)\right]=0$

> I don't have ideea how can I prove that $f$ have all real roots

Suppose that $z=a+bi$ and we need to prove that $b=0$:

$$\Rightarrow f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{10}\left(\dbinom{10}{k}\cdot a^{10-k}\cdot i^k\right) \left[(b+1)^k+(b-1)^k \right]=0$$

$$\Rightarrow \left[(b+1)^k+(b-1)^k \right]=0$$

$$\Rightarrow b+1=-b+1$$
$$\Rightarrow b=0$$

Therefore $f$ have all the roots in $\mathbb{R}$

- Here is a photo with the proof of real axis, I don't know if is correct:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a+ib$ be an imaginary root of $f$ , where , $a,b\in \mathbb R$.
Then $$f(a+ib)=0$$

$$\implies (a+i(b+1))^{10}+(a+i(b-1))^{10}=0$$

Expand two binomial series , and separate real part and imaginary parts. Put them separately $0$. Then you obtain the value of $b$, which would be zero, if the problem is proper.

Comment: S.Panja from here I have to expand $(a+i(b+1))^{10}$ in binominal series?

Comment: I cancel your downvote

Comment: Panja I will edit with binominal series and I want to tell me if is correct

Comment: Panja is correct ?

Answer (score 22):

$(x+i)^{10}+(x-i)^{10}=0$ immediately implies $|x+i|=|x-i|$, which is equivalent to $x \in \mathbb R$ (the real axis is the perpendicular bisector of the line from $i$ to $-i$).

Comment: can you give me a draw ? because I don't know to make it

Comment: What exactly you do not know/understand about this proof? Be more precise.

Comment: MooS I can't understand your method, can you give some explanations ?

Comment: If the sum of two complex numbers is zero, there euclidean norm is of course the same. And for the second assertion: You can easily compute this with $x = u+iv$. And you can use the geometric viewpoint, which is slightly nicer I think.

Comment: MooS where I find this affirmation: "If the sum of two complex numbers is zero, there euclidean  norm is...". For instance: suppose that we have :  $(1+i)+(-1-i)=0\Rightarrow |1+i|=|-1-i|=\sqrt{2}\neq 0$

Comment: Yes, the euclidean norms are the same. So where is the problem?

Comment: in our case we have $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ and we say that is equivalent to $x\in\mathbb{R}$ because we see $x+i=a+bi$ with $a=x\in\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @Lucas: |x+i| is the distance of $x$ from $-i$ and $|x-i|$ is the distance of $x$ from $i$. The locus of points that are equidistant from $-i$ and $i$ is the real axis.

Comment: @robjohn how you figure out that $|x+i|$ is the distance of $x$ from $-i$ and ....

Comment: @robjohn I upload a photo with my draw and I want to say if is good, I think I understand :D

Comment: I think is wrong but I don't know why

Comment: @Lucas: $|x+i|=|x-(-i)|$, so $|x+i|$ is the distance from $x$ to $-i$.

Comment: and the neccessary condition for which $(x+i)^{10}=-(x-i)^{10}$ is $|x+i|=|x-i|$ but how I would have realized this :-?

Comment: While one root of $(x+i)^{10}+(x-i)^{10}=0$ is given by $|x+i|=|x-i|$, there are other roots.  You have not shown that these lead to real $x$.  Letting $z=(x+i)/(x-i)$ we have $z^{10}=-1 \implies |z^{10}|=1\implies |z|=e^{in\pi/5}$ for $n =0, \pm 1,\pm 2\pm3,\pm4,5$, which give the $10$ roots.  Now you need to show that all of these lead to $x$ as real valued.

Comment: All roots satisfy $|x-i|=|x+i|$. So this works fine without further arguments.

Answer (score 5):

$(x+i)^{10} = -(x-i)^{10} = i^{10}(x-i)^{10} = (i(x-i))^{10} \to \left(\dfrac{x+i}{ix+1}\right)^{10} = 1$. Can you continue??

Comment: notaloner I can't understand how you obtain $\left(\frac{x+i}{1+ix}\right)^{10}$ and I can't continue

Comment: first, $i(x-i) = ix - i^2 = ix+1$, and secondly use $a^{10} = b^{10} \iff \left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^{10} = 1$

Comment: NotALoner if I continue your method I obtain something like this $\frac{(x+i)(ix-1)}{-x^2-1}=1\Rightarrow x^2(-1-i)+2x+i-1=0$ and I suppose  we need to put condition that: $4-4(-1-i)(i-1)\geq 0$ isn't it ?

Comment: after I obtain: $-4\geq 0$ which is a contradiction

Comment: can you explain what you want by this method ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way of showing that all solution are real valued.

$(x+i)^{10}+(x-i)^{10}=0\implies\,\,\left(\frac{x+i}{x-i}\right)^{10}=e^{in\pi}\implies \frac{x+i}{x-i}=e^{in\pi/10} \implies x=\cot(n\pi/20)$

which are real-valued for all integer $n$.

---

To answer the question regarding the substitution $z=a+ib$ and subsequent analysis, if $(b+1)^k+(b-1)^k=0$, then this implies that $b=-i\cot (n\pi/2k)$ for all integer $n$ and $k=0, 1, 2, \cdots 10$.

But, since $b$ is presumed to be real valued, then this implies $b=0$ (i.e., only solutions with $n/k$ odd are valid).

However, this assumption (i.e., $(b+1)^k+(b-1)^k=0$) is not the basis for a proof that $b=0$.

Comment: @Lucas I'm not sure that this is what you were looking for, but hope that it helps.

Comment: Dr.Mv why $(x+i)^{10}+(x-i)^{10}$ leds to absolute value: $|x+i|=|x-i|$ ?

Comment: @Lucas Well, that result was not used here.  But you recall that $|z|^n=|z^n|$.  So, letting $z=\frac{x+i}{x-i}$, we have $|z^{10}|=|-1| \implies |z|^{10}=1\implies |z|=1$ is one root.  But there are other roots.

Comment: Dr.Mv how can I continue my solution with binominal series ?

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the equation in

$$\left(\frac{x+i}{x-i}\right)^{10}=-1=z^{10}.$$

Then, solving for $x$ and using $|z|=1$,
$$x=i\frac{z+1}{z-1}=i\frac{(z+1)(\overline z-1)}{(z-1)(\overline z-1)}=i\frac{|z|^2-1+\overline z-z}{|z|^2+1-z-\overline z}=\frac{2\Im z}{2-2\Re z}.$$

Comment: my binominal series is correct ?

Comment: Yes but the conclusion you draw from it is not.

Comment: and how can I continue at final ?

Comment: Leads you to a system of two polynomial equations in two unknowns.

Comment: and which is two polynomial equations ?

Comment: $\Re f(z)=\Im f(z)=0$.

Comment: Yves who's the real part ?

Comment: Yves I can't see the real part, is think is 0

Answer (score 1):

$x=a+bi$

$$(x+i)^{10}+(x-i)^{10}=0 \Rightarrow (x+i)^{10}=-(x-i)^{10} \Rightarrow (\frac{x+i}{x-i})^{10}=-1 \\ \Rightarrow \left (\frac{a+(b+1)i}{a+(b-1)i}\right )^{10}=i^{10} \Rightarrow \frac{a+(b+1)i}{a+(b-1)i}=i \\ \Rightarrow \frac{(a+(b+1)i)(a-(b-1)i)}{(a+(b-1)i)(a-(b-1)i)}=i \Rightarrow \frac{a^2-a(b-1)i+a(b+1)i+(b^2-1)}{a^2+(b-1)^2}=i \Rightarrow \frac{(a^2+(b^2-1))+2ai}{a^2+(b-1)^2}=i$$

That means that $$\frac{a^2+(b^2-1)}{a^2+(b-1)^2}=0 \text{ and } \frac{2a}{a^2+(b-1)^2}=1$$

$$\frac{a^2+(b^2-1)}{a^2+(b-1)^2}=0 \Rightarrow a^2+b^2-1=0 \Rightarrow b^2=1-a^2$$

$$\frac{2a}{a^2+(b-1)^2}=1 \Rightarrow 2a=a^2+(b-1)^2 \Rightarrow 2a=a^2+b^2-2b+1 $$

Solving for $a$ and $b$ we get the following solutions:

$a=0, b=1$ and $a=1, b=0$

We reject $(a, b)=(0, 1)$ because then the denominator would be $0$.

So, the solution is $(a, b)=(1, 0)$.

That means that $x=1 \in \mathbb{R}$.

$$$$

Do the same for the case $\left (\frac{a+(b+1)i}{a+(b-1)i}\right )^{10}=i^{10} \Rightarrow \frac{a+(b+1)i}{a+(b-1)i}=-i$

Comment: Mary Star what's wrong in my binominal series ? I can't see the real part in my solution

Comment: You can't go from $x^{10}=y^{10}$ to $x=y$ as you do in the second line of your proof here.

Comment: why it can't do it ?