# Where am I wrong in $\int_0^1 x(1-x)^ndx$

Tags: calculus, integration

We have $\int_0^1 x(1-x)^ndx=-\frac{x(1-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}|^{^1}_{_0}+\frac{(1-x)^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}|^{^1}_{_0}=-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$

If I use substitution $u=1-x\Rightarrow \int_0^1 (1-u)u^n du=\frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}|^{^1}_{_0}-\frac{u^{n+2}}{n+2}|^{^1}_{_0}=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$

> Where am I wrong ?

Comment: You forgot to change the limits?

Comment: abcz I change limits of integration $-du=dx\Rightarrow -\int_1^0 .. du = \int_0^1... du$

Comment: of course, but don't think this is problem

Comment: Your first integral is incorrect: note that you are integrating a nonnegative function, so the answer should be nonnegative. Check the signs in your integration by parts.

Comment: I was thought at it but can't explain where is the miss of sign, can you show ?

Comment: You should have avoided to skip a step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sentence is not correct :

$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{1}x(1-x)^ndx&=\int_{0}^{1}x\left(\frac{-(1-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)'dx\\&=\left[x\left(\frac{-(1-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)\right]_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{-(1-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}dx\\&=\left[x\left(\frac{-(1-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)\right]_{0}^{1}\color{red}{-}\left[\frac{(1-x)^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right]_{0}^{1}\end{align}$$

Comment: math I change limits of integration $-du=dx\Rightarrow -\int_1^0 .. du = \int_0^1... du$

Comment: @Lucas: I was wrong. sorry. I edited my answer.

Comment: yes, I realized after too

Comment: mathlove can you help at my recent question ?

Answer (score 1):

**REVISED BY REQUEST**

We begin with the integral $\int_0^1 x(1-x)^ndx$.  Integrating by parts gives

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 x(1-x)^ndx&=\left.-\frac{x(1-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right|^{^1}_{_0}+\frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^1 (1-x)^{n+1}dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^1 (1-x)^{n+1}dx
\end{align}$$

Now, integrating the remaining term reveals that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^1 (1-x)^{n+1}dx&=-\frac{1}{n+1}\left.\frac{(1-x)^{n+2}}{n+2}\right|^{^1}_{_0}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}
\end{align}$$

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 x(1-x)^ndx&=\left.-\frac{x(1-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right|^{^1}_{_0}\color{red}{-}\left.\frac{(1-x)^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right|^{^1}_{_0}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Dr.Mv indeed if we have minus between is correct, but why we have minus ? if  we have $x\cdot \left(-\frac{(1-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)$ and by integration $\int_0^1 ... dx= -(...)\color{red}{-}\left(\color{red}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\int_0^1 (1-x)^{n+1} dx$

Comment: @Lucas I'll edit

Comment: @Lucas, you get another negative when you compute the integral of $(1-x)^{n+1}$.

Comment: now I understand, thanks, if you want can put at answer @SantiagoCanez

Comment: Dr. Mv at the **REVISED BY REQUEST at the final row you don't have $\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{(1-x)^{n+2}}{n+2}$

Comment: @Lucas Yes.  I caught that and edited accordingly.  Thanks!  Let me know how I can further improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: Dr.Mv take a look here, I really need your help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313011/prove-that-f-xi10x-i10-have-all-real-roots

Comment: @Lucas  It seems that there have been others who have answered that one.

Comment: @Dr.MV  no, I want some explanations look at my binominal series, I can't see the real part, how can I separate the real part of the imaginary part ? what's wrong in my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by a simple move: Let $u = 1-x$, then the integral becomes a much simpler one: $I = \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 (u^n-u^{n+1})du$. And you can take it from here...

Comment: yes, I think I can...